# Destructing properties passed to child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone help me in understanding how destructing works?

Suppose we have a component having **`component` as `props`**

i.e

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = (props)=> {

  console.log(props)
```

Here **`console.log(props)`** is giving following result

```
{path: "/auth", component: ƒ, prop: {…}, location: {…}, computedMatch: {…}}
component: ƒ Connect(props)
computedMatch: {path: "/auth", url: "/auth", isExact: true, params: {…}}
location: {pathname: "/auth", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
path: "/auth"
prop: {isAuthenticated: false}
```

Now, If I destructure and write the above code like this

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = ({component: Component, ...props})=> {
  console.log(component)
```

It throws an error saying component is not defined but if I

```
 console.log(Component)
```

It logs `component` which was in props.

Based on my vaguely understanding of Javascript, I think that we store/assign value to javascript object by keeping the value to be stored on right and to which it is to be assigned in left

like

```
name: Anny
```

inside an object will assign value to property name as anny.

Can someone explain me why I am getting result for `console.log(Component)` and not for  `console.log(component)`

Comment: I suggest you to read more about ES6 syntax before digging into React. This will save you hours with issues like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `{component: Component,` in your function definition means, "I want the value of the "component" property of the object parameter, and I would like it to be *called* "Component" in the function." In other words, it *renames* the parameter from the default, which is the source property name.

If you wrote

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = ({component, ...props})=> {
  console.log(component)
```

then it would work. The name of the parameter in the function would be the same as the name of the property in the passed-in object.

I agree that it's a little confusing, because in an object initializer the `:` separates the property name (on the left) from the value expression on the right. In particular, the value expression has nothing to do with creating a name for anything. In the destructuring syntax, however, the `:` is used differently. There are only so many punctuation characters on a keyboard.

Comment: It occurs to me (for what it's worth, which is nothing) that adopting the SQL `as` might have been nice: `function foo({ component as Component, ... props })`. I guess that would have introduced a new semi-reserved word maybe.

Comment: Pointy, Can you please share a link so that I can read more about this? i am not sure what to Google.

Comment: @anny123 [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) — also if you google "javascript destructuring tutorial" there are a bunch of pretty good posts out there.